# My contents are left aligned in IE 7?

Tags: html, css

I have a outer div which is working correctly in chrome, firefox but not in IE.. I have some contents inside outer div.. to make it center aligned or middle of page i gave this width:970px; height:630px; to outer div... so that i got the contents at the center in chrome and Mozilla... but in the case of IE 7.. in IE its left aligned..

here is my css....

```
<style type="text/css">
body, html 
{ 
    font-family:helvetica,arial,sans-serif; 
    font-size:90%; 
}
div.outer 
{  
    display: block; 
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width:970px;
    height:630px;
    position:relative;
}
</style>
```

here is my full code:

```
<head><title>home</title>
</head><body class='claro'><div class='outer' style="border:1px solid black;">
<div id="dottedBorderhome">
</div>
<div id="dragIconhome">
</div>
<div class="claro" id="menuDiv2" onclick="setWidgetproperty(this.id,'x','navMenu2');" onmousedown="setMenuBarProperty('navMenu2');" onmouseup="setDocStyle(this.id)" style="border: 1px dotted white; left: auto; position: absolute; top: 17px;">
     <!-- here one menu bar will come -->
</div>
<div class="claro" id="divlabel43" onclick="setWidgetproperty(this.id,null,'divlabel43')" onmouseup="setDocStyle(this.id)" style="left: 50px; position: absolute; top: 92px; text-align: right; font-family: Times; font-size: 15pt; font-weight: bold;" >
     <label id="label43" onclick="setLblProperty(this.id)" onmouseover="editName('divlabel43',this.id,'label')">
          Worklist Manager
     </label>
</div>
<div class="claro" id="htmlTableDiv9" onmouseup="setDocStyle(this.id)" style="left: auto; position: absolute; top: 130px; height:70px; width:150px;">
     <!-- here its contains table -->
</div>
<div class="claro" id="divImage2" onclick="setWidgetproperty(this.id,'xy','image2')" onmouseup="setDocStyle(this.id)" style="left: auto; position: absolute; top: 70px;">
     <img class="images" id="image2" name="Search-icon2.png" onclick="setImgProperty(this.id)" src="images/uploads/Search-icon2.png" style="height: 50px; width: 58px;">
</div>

<div class="claro" id="menuDiv1" onclick="setWidgetproperty(this.id,'x','navMenu1');" onmousedown="setMenuBarProperty('navMenu1');" onmouseup="setDocStyle(this.id)" style="border:1px dotted white; left: auto; position: absolute; top: 640px;">
     <!-- here another menu bar -->
</div>

<div id="CWPWORKLIST__1" onclick="setWidgetproperty(this.id,'xy','inner__CWPWORKLIST__1')" ondblclick="editDataGridResponseMapping(this.id)" onmouseup="setDocStyle(this.id)" style="left:auto; position:absolute; top:340px; height: 296px; width: 921px;">
     <!-- here another table-->
</div>
</div></body>
```

Comment: A div is by default a block level element, you don't need to tell it again :)

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742877/center-align-div-in-internet-explorer

Comment: apply `margin:auto;` to the `div.outer`'s parent element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Sven suggested, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742877/center-align-div-in-internet-explorer likely holds your answer. Either you've got non-valid HTML that is putting IE7 in quirks mode, or you're missing the doctype.

Comment: pretty sure this is it. missing doctype most likely.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<style type="text/css">
body, html 
{ 
    font-family:helvetica,arial,sans-serif; 
    font-size:90%; 
}
div.outer 
{  
    display: block; 
    margin:0 auto;
    width:970px;
    height:630px;
    position:relative;
}
</style>
```

Comment: The difference is margin:0 auto;

Comment: Changing a property to shorthand doesn't really contribute anything.

Comment: i tried... am not getting... its still the same... please help me??

Answer (score 0):

Use code with proper doc type.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```